# How do I monitor the cost of updating statistics on a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that has 2 billion+ rows and 7 indexes across 8 partitions that only has the standard SQL Server `AUTOUPDATE` to maintain the statistics, which only updates the statistics very infrequently. Approximately 1.3 million records are added to this table nightly. Clearly this is not behavior that makes sense, but as this is a production server, I am very wary of just hitting update without knowing the performance cost. I do not have the full table in any test environment. (This table is the worst offender, there are others that are almost as bad.)

Where/What should I be looking at when determining the performance costs associated with updating statistics regularly?

How often should the statistics be updated? Should `FULLSCAN` ever be used?

EDIT

I am thinking that traceflag 2371 would be a dangerous tool for me to use as it can trigger its own updates during the day when I need everything up and running as opposed to a window that I control.

After doing quite a bit more research I think this question has evolved to include whether to use `sp_updatestats` (which seems like a sledgehammer, as it updates stats if >1 row has been updated [Erin Stellato](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/07/sql-statistics/statistics-updates)) or `UPDATE STATISTICS` and if `UPDATE STATISTICS` then what percentage on a table that large. 10% sample on a billion rows took about 2 hours to finish.

If it is relevant part of the PK is an ascending datetime column.

END EDIT

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 or newer version, try to use trace flag 2371. It decreases update threshold.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saponsqlserver/archive/2011/09/13/10207658.aspx

Comment: This is good info, but it doesn't tell me what the cost is going to be to be updating statistics on these tables regularly, I imagine I am best off updating every day, but I ran a test on my dev environment with `FULLSCAN` on half (1 billion rows) of this huge table, it took 7 hours to complete on a machine doing nothing else, I don't have that many hours available as a statistics update window on any given day.

Comment: 1. In regular situations you don't need FULLSCAN ever.

Comment: 2. I don't understand why you don't want to use T2371. It doesn't cause stats update with fullscan.

Comment: I don't want to trigger an update outside my maintenance window, I imagine the update would be kicked off in middle of my nightly upload process and cause bottlenecks for resources which I am trying to avoid. I have multiple uploads being processed daily.

Comment: What's a "regular situation"?

Comment: Update performs asynchronously

Comment: Not by default, and may not be best practice anyway. [BrentOzar](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/auto-update-stats-async-enabled/)